# How to Display Stock Report Based on TAble

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 6 tables:

1. inwardmaster
2. openingstock
3. itemmaster
4. adjustment
5. extraissue
6. bomupload

these are the table common field is item barcode while im tring the sql code here:

```
SELECT item.*,(item.item_quantity+op.opening_stock+bom.quantitytopick+adj.adjustment_quantity) as totalquality 
FROM 
itemmaster item 
left join openingstock op on item.item_barcode = op.item_barcode 
inner join bomupload bom on op.item_barcode = bom.item_barcode 
inner join adjustment_inventory adj on bom.item_barcode = adj.item_barcode
```

output comes all the table entry will be there display.

but i want display  itemmaster table all field  and quantity if 0 also display based on select query.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If itemmaster table is master table and item_barcode is foreignkey referred in all other table, try following query:

```
SELECT item.*,
    (item.item_quantity + op.opening_stock + bom.quantitytopick + adj.adjustment_quantity) as totalquality 
FROM 
itemmaster item 
LEFT JOIN openingstock op on item.item_barcode = op.item_barcode 
LEFT JOIN bomupload bom on item.item_barcode = bom.item_barcode 
LEFT JOIN adjustment_inventory adj on item.item_barcode = adj.item_barcode
```

Comment: this query execute only 1000 line items but i want dispaly all items as per item master

Comment: that is mysql workbench constraint... Please follow this link to change preferences and you may see all the records. 
 https://superuser.com/questions/240291/how-to-remove-1000-row-limit-in-mysql-workbench-queries

Comment: 1 lakh items in database quantity also not adding and display

Comment: If your columns list used for summation can contain null value, then use like below:   SELECT item.*,
    (IFNULL(item.item_quantity,0) + IFNULL(op.opening_stock,0)  + IFNULL(bom.quantitytopick + IFNULL(adj.adjustment_quantity,0) ) as totalquality

Comment: Also, double check column names and their datatype.

Comment: #1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'IFNULL' error occur

Comment: Some text went missing. Try this:
SELECT item.*, (IFNULL(item.item_quantity,0) + IFNULL(op.opening_stock,0) + IFNULL(bom.quantitytopick,0) + IFNULL(adj.adjustment_quantity,0) ) as totalquality –

Comment: SELECT item.*, COALESCE(item.item_quantity + op.passedquantity + bom.quantitytopick + adj.adjustment_quantity,0) as totalquality FROM itemmaster item LEFT JOIN inwardmaster op on item.item_barcode = op.item_barcode LEFT JOIN bomupload bom on item.uniquecode = bom.uniquecode LEFT JOIN adjustment_inventory adj on item.item_barcode = adj.item_barcode   this will be working but quantity not adding

Comment: Is data type for all those fields you are trying to add are numeric?

Comment: yes i want add all data using itembarcode but i want double entries in onetable also added

Comment: SELECT item.*, (IFNULL(item.item_quantity,0) + IFNULL(op.opening_stock,0) + IFNULL(bom.quantitytopick,0) + IFNULL(adj.adjustment_quantity,0) ) as totalquality
FROM 
itemmaster item 
LEFT JOIN openingstock op on item.item_barcode = op.item_barcode 
LEFT JOIN bomupload bom on item.uniquecode = bom.uniquecode 
LEFT JOIN adjustment_inventory adj on item.item_barcode = adj.item_barcode                                    //in this  one if double entry same item in any table combine quantity and display  how

Comment: Try with INNER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN if you need to calculate multiple anyried and then use group by item.barcode. Use SUM(your column names here) instead of plain addition we were doing earlier.

Comment: SELECT item.*, SUM(IFNULL(item.item_quantity,0) + IFNULL(op.opening_stock,0) + IFNULL(bom.quantitytopick,0) + IFNULL(adj.adjustment_quantity,0) ) as totalquality FROM itemmaster item INNER JOIN openingstock op on item.item_barcode = op.item_barcode INNER JOIN bomupload bom on item.uniquecode = bom.uniquecode INNER JOIN adjustment_inventory adj on item.item_barcode = adj.item_barcode GroupBy item.barcode

Comment: But it shows null value i want to display all sum of quantity with single entry also add and double entry also add and any one table entry there also add itemmaster table

Comment: Group by should show it as single entry only. For each barcode you will get one entry.

Comment: but i want any one table data entry there quantity add and display